# Enhanced Image Cropping

Tags: java, image-processing

Which is best java library to do cropping.The aim is to maintain the clarity of the cropped image at 2x zoom.The sides of cropped image are getting blurred while zooming to 2X level.I tried Java advanced imaging(JAI) to crop with rendering hints.I also tried RescaleDescriptor(JAI) to enhance the image.But it works only for a black particle in a white background.Is there any other libraries which i can use?

Comment: Are you resizing prior to cropping?

Comment: no. I am only doing the cropping

Comment: So.. do the resizing first.  I thought that would have been obviously implied.

Answer (score 8):

Using [Thumbnailator](https://github.com/coobird/thumbnailator), one can crop the original image and zoom into that region with the following code:

```
Thumbnails.of("/path/to/image")
    .sourceRegion(Positions.CENTER, 100, 100)
    .scale(2.0)
    .resizer(Resizers.BICUBIC)
    .toFile("/path/to/cropped+zoomed-image");
```

The above will take the central 100 px by 100 px region of the source image and enlarge it by a scaling factor of 2.0x using [bicubic interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation) to result in a smooth image without jagged edges:

[image: Source image (left) cropped and enlarged by Thumbnailator (right)]
<sub>(source: [coobird.net](http://coobird.net/img/zoom-in.jpg))</sub>

Although Thumbnailator is a library which specializes in creating thumbnails (hence the name), it can usually be adapted to create enlarged images as well.

*Full disclosure: I am the developer of Thumbnailator.*

Comment: Happy to have finally met you coobird. I use your library on my site and it works great. Thank you for creating such a nifty tool.

Answer (score 4):

Before using external libraries try setting these rendering hints (for "normal" swing rendering):

```
g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                   RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR); // or .._BICUBIC

g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
                   RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                   RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

---

The code below produces this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage o = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png"));
    final BufferedImage image = o.getSubimage(220, 220, 80, 80);
    final int width  = image.getWidth() * 4;
    final int height = image.getHeight() * 4;

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));

    frame.add(new JComponent() {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                                 RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
                                 RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                                 RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

            g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, null);
        }
    });
    frame.add(new JComponent() {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, null);
        }
    });

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(649, 351);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/), a great library for image processing.

Here is a code example for cropping :

```
ImageProcessor ip = //... get the image processor to crop
ip.setRoi(left,top,width,height); //set the "Region Of Interest" (rectangle within the image) 
ImageProcessor ip2 = ip.crop();
```